# Cognito verify password without triggering sign in

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm  using Cognito and Amplify and I'm looking for something that I don't know if it's possible.

I'm trying to add an extra layer of security to our app by asking the user to confirm his password every time they open our app (just like a lot of banking apps will do). It's not exactly a sign-in since they are already signed-in and have a valid token, but I want to confirm that they're the right person with the password again to prevent someone taking another person's phone and seeing the content of the app.

It's quite easy to just call signIn again even if they're already signed-in, but with 2fa authentication turned on, this will trigger a challenge and I want to avoid it. Anyone knows if there's a way to just validate the password without triggering a signIn flow in Cognito? Or maybe there's a way to tellCognito to not ask for 2fa again on this device (like it's done on many other websites like Amazon, ...)

I couldn't find any info online about something like this, but I feels like not asking 2fa's OTP code on every sign in for a specific device is a pretty widespread practice so I'm kinda surprised to not see it in Cognito.

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I am attempting the same thing. Did you have any luck?